# "Distinct on substring" query in Kibana 4

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I would like to know how can I get a "distinct on substring" query in Kibana 4.

For example, I would to group "message" by a subsequence, such as this :

Row logs:

```
Timestamp  | Level | Message
2015-03-31 | ERROR | Something is wrong
2015-03-31 | ERROR | Something is still wrong
2015-03-31 | INFO  | Problem seams to be fixed
2015-03-31 | WARN  | There may be a problem
```

The expected result would be:

```
wrong:   2
problem: 2
fixed:   1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using term on analyzed field (i.e message in this case) .You can include words you want in term.